# How to use Perl's File::Find::Rule module to find files with 777 perms

Tags: perl, rules

I want to use perl File::Find::Rule in order to find files in the server that have perms 777

I know that the module has stats tests so i could simply do this:

```
$rule->mode(33279)
```

I found the 33279 by creating a file and printing the permission on it assuming that File::Find::Rule takes decimal? or should it be formatted somehow?

Is this the right approach to have all the file that have  exactly the 777 permissions?

this is a script that finds all files on the home dir of a test server.. i want to change it so that it only finds those with 777 permissions.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $rule = File::Find::Rule->new;
$rule->file;
$rule->name( '*' );
my @files = $rule->in( "/root" );

for my $file (@files) {
     my $mode = (stat $file)[2];
     printf ("%04o %s\n",$mode & 07777, $file);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mode` includes the file permissions *and type*. You need to mask it so that you only get the permission bits. Personally I'd implement a custom rule:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::stat;
use Fcntl qw/S_IMODE/;
use File::Find::Rule 'rule';

my $rule = rule->file->exec(sub{ S_IMODE(stat($_[2])->mode)==0777 });

my @files = $rule->in('/root');
for my $file (@files) {
    print $file, "\n";
}
```

Note that this masked mode still includes the setuid/setgid/sticky bits (often known as `Xst`). If you want to ignore those too, and check only the `ugo`/`rwx` bits, then you'd have to mask against `0777` (e.g. `$mode & 0777`).

Comment: do you need somehow to convert the base of the output of mode?  if i run the stats command on a file i get the value of 33279 which in octal would mean 100777? what the 3 ciffers before the 777? I asume it is the uid/gid?

Comment: No, those are the file type and setuid/setgid/sticky bits. Octal is just another way to represent an integer, so for comparing values in your program, you don't need to convert anything - in the Perl source code, `0100777` is the same as `33279`. For output in octal, you can use `printf`/`sprintf`, for example `printf "%04o", 0644;` prints `0644`. To convert a Perl string that contains an octal number to an integer, Perl provides the `oct` function: `print oct("664");` prints `436`, in other words, `oct("664") == 436 == 0664`.

Comment: Regarding the `mode` bits, see e.g. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html

Answer (score -1):

Using `File::Find::Rule` is cool, but you could do it easily with `find` and get the answers back in perl:

```
@files = split /\n/, `/bin/find /root -perm 777`;
```